# How to size a paragraph the same height as an image

Tags: html, css, image, image-resizing

Trying to get the paragraph to be the same size as the image on the right as it. currently it is the bottom of the paragraph changes size but the top is fixed

[kid with toy cars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slQ99.jpg)

my CSS code is

```
.kid{
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50%;
}


.paragraph{
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 50%;
    font-size-adjust: auto;
    background-color: #3498db;
    color:white;
    font-style: italic;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

and my HTML code is

```
<div>       
<img class = "kid" src="kid%20playing%20toy%20pic.jpg">
</div>      
    
       
<div class = "para">    
<section class="paragraph">
    <p> "text" </p>  
</section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you want the size of the image to be dynamic with the length of the paragraph, I would use a 2-column `flex` layout with the second div containing the image as `background-image`. Do it this way is responsive because the height of the `image-div` will change as the paragraph gets smaller or larger.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  flex: auto;
}

.paragraph {
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
  width: 50%;
}

.image-div {
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h6> smaller </h6>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged </p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-div">

  </div>
</div>


<h6> larger </h6>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="paragraph">
    <p> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It
      has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text
      ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. Lorem Ipsum
      is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="image-div">

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

not entirely clear what you actually want.  Use flex.

```css
.paragraph {
  display: flex; 
  justify-content:space-between;
  background-color: #3498db;
  color: white;
  font-style: italic;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<section class="paragraph">
  <p> "text" </p>
  <img class="kid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150">
</section>
```